# What version of PCL is my file? Convert a PCL 3 monochrome Driver to PCL 5e

Tags: c++, c, printer-control-language

Back in December 2019 a bug was submitted that the print from our custom legacy driver is fuzzy.
The driver was developed in 2006 by a developer at our company. It is a bitmap driver that outputs PCL. The developer wrote the PCL driver and PCL To tiff converter. It still works and customers love it.
Some customers report that the print is fuzzy. As a person with no driver development background, I sought help on forum. Some forum members have helped me figure out that this it is a monochrome driver and so the print is fuzzy. Some customers have also asked for a color driver. The 2 necessary functionalities are fix the fuzziness primarily and then color would be good.

Printing is also done directly from a document but the complicated workflow is the one from HP 5Si. I could totally get rid of PCL for our driver and make it XPS (which I tried) but it is not compatible with Hp 5Si workflow.
I also made sure it is the PCL generated by our legacy driver not the converter. I also use Ghost PCL and output was fuzzy there too.

I hope that made some sense to you. Now after one year, I am back to working on the driver.
I really thought our driver is outputting PCL3 and so the fuzziness. But if you say its PCL5, then I would need to figure out why? Its hard to find samples for PCL. Then i have the problem of figuring out converter PCLtoTiff which is in C# but still feels like greek and latin.

I would like to know what version of PCL does HP5Si output?
I used a application called PclParaphernalia and this is how the commands look. It is not the complete file, just the beginning. I don't see 'Switch To HP-GL/2 command' which is weird.
[image]

Ending
[image]

Driver 2.
The second driver is our legacy driver. I would also like to know what version of PCL it outputs.

I am just guessing it is PCL3 since it was written around 2006. How do I know what version of PCL is it outputting?
Driver 1 is not in my control. If I upgrade driver 2, can I upgrade it to PCL5?  What about compatibility?

Finally,

Can anyone point me to the differences in PCL commands between PCL 3 and PCL 5e?
If the second driver is written in PCL 5 then great!. If not  I would like to attempt to convert it to PCL5. The driver is originally a bitmap driver which outputs PCL code.
Where should I start. The code is written in C, C++.
Are there any sample projects I could use for PCL 5 code in C++?

EDIT:
The driver starts out with this sample
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/bitmap

Code got added to emit  PCLRasterGraphicPage inside a file called ddihook.cpp. PC
PCLRasterGraphicPage takes a SURFOBJ.

Fuzzy image
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: That's PCL5 and you should not give even a passing thought to anything older than that; PCL5 was introduced in 1990 and the HP 5Si has never supported PCL3.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Thank you. So the two screenshots are PCL5.? May I ask you to please elaborate? HP 5 SSI has never supported PCL3? Then how does it work with the legacy driver. How do you know its PCL5? The legacy driver may output PCL5. Pardon my questions. I am not a driver developer.

Comment: I've worked with printers for a long time and the above just *looks* like PCL5, it jumps out at me. Can you be more specific about what big-picture problem you're solving? You would not be talking about moving drivers around unless something was driving the issue.

Comment: Sure.  I will explain it. Is it Ok if I email it to you at steve@unixwiz.net? . If not I will just edit the question

Comment: It's better to keep these here where everybody can benefit, though I'll revisit this in the morning when I get up.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: @SteveFriedl: I added some history to the problem. Please feel to comment or ask any questions.

Comment: Good place to start is the PCL reference manual from HP: https://developers.hp.com/system/files/PCL_5_Printer_Language_Technical_Reference_Manual.pdf and it has everything you need to know about it. Hard to say why things are fuzzy, I wonder if text is being created to raster in the driver and then the bitmap scaled in the printer; that would be a poor way to do printing.  Does the driver send text to the printer, or send bitmaps to the printer?

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Thank you for that information. I edited the question with the sample it was taken from and some more information. I do not understand this line "Does the driver send text to the printer, or send bitmaps to the printer?".  Where do I check? The driver starts out as bitmap and then sends PCL commands to the printer. Any code samples you have would greatly help to illustrate this "text is being created to raster in the driver and then the bitmap scaled in the printer".

Comment: @SteveFriedl: I promise I am quick learner. I just need some help on what to look to answer your questions. Like I said I am not a driver developer. This project is something we have to work on out of necessity to support our customers.

Comment: If the driver is creating a bitmap and then sending that bitmap to the printer, then it doesn't matter much whether that bitmap is conveyed to the printer via PCL or PostScript or anything else, and changing the driver to send native text (rather than bitmap) is going to be far beyond what a Stack Overflow question can really address, I'm afraid.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Got it. thank you for that explanation.  I edited my question with a sample of the fuzziness customers are complaining. First of all how do I even attempt to convert a file that has lots of pictures inside the graphic to native text? See the picture in the seal, it has text inside the picture. How can this be converted to native text? Any Microsoft samples to help me?  Thank you very much

Comment: The seal is inherently an image, and this looks like a resolution mismatch.  I'm afraid you're probably going to have to find a driver developer to help you (which is not me).

Comment: @SteveFriedl: Great thanks :) Any suggestions for decent driver products or developers? I am not one either.